Prove of rules of operation with limits that diverge
Could someone help to check my proof, I'm not sure if they are rigorous:
Given ${a_n}$, ${b_n}$, and ${c_n}$ be sequences of real numbers and let k be a constant, $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = \infty$, and $\lim_{n \to \infty} c_n = -\infty$.
To prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_nb_n = \infty$, we fix any $M \in \mathbb{R} $. Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$, $\exists N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n \ge \sqrt{M}$ $\forall n \ge N_1$. Similarly, $\exists N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $b_n \ge \sqrt{M}$ $\forall n \ge N_2$. Let $N=max${$N_1,N_2$}. Then, $a_nb_n \ge M$ $\forall n \ge N$, which implies the claim.
To prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_nc_n = -\infty$, we fix any $M \in \mathbb{R} $. Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$, $\exists N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n \ge \sqrt{M}$ $\forall n \ge N_1$. Similarly, $\exists N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $c_n \le \sqrt{M}$ $\forall n \ge N_2$. We can also write it as $-c_n \ge \sqrt{M}$. Let $N=max${$N_1,N_2$}. Then, $-a_nc_n \ge -M$ which is $a_nc_n \le M$ $\forall n \ge N$, which implies the claim.
To prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} ka_n = \infty$ if $k \gt 0$, and $\lim_{n \to \infty} ka_n = -\infty$ if $k \lt 0$, we fix any $M \in \mathbb{R} $. Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n \ge \frac{M}{k}$ $\forall n \ge N$. If $k \gt 0$, then $ka_n \ge M$, else if $k \lt 0$, then $ka_n \le M$, which implies the claim.

One thing you should pay attention to: $\sqrt{M}$ is only defined when $M$ is non-negative, so you should add this precision in your first and second proof. Other than that, the first proof is correct.

I am assuming you forgot a minus sign in your second proof: "Similarly, $\exists N_2 \in \Bbb N$ such that $c_n \le - \sqrt{M}$...". Now that you have $a_n  \ge \sqrt{M}$ and $-c_n \ge \sqrt{M}$ for all $n \ge N$, you can indeed multiply these two inequalities termwise because every term is positive (you have to be more careful if negative numbers are involved). Then, you find $-a_n c_n \ge M$ (no minus sign on the right), which shows that $-a_n c_n \rightarrow -\infty$, hence $a_n c_n \rightarrow \infty$.

Third proof is correct.

Oops, I'm sorry, it should be $-c_n \ge -\sqrt{M}$ and $-a_nc_n \ge -M$ which is $a_nc_n \le M$ $\forall n \ge N$, which implies $a_nc_n \to -\infty$ as $\lim_{n \to \infty} c_n = -\infty$.

When you write $-c_n \ge - \sqrt{M}$, you do not really gather any information. Indeed, as $-c_n$ tends to infinity, it will be positive at some point, whereas $-\sqrt{M}$ is a negative number. So stating this inequality will prevent you from moving forward. Indeed your conclusion is false: $a_n c_n \le M$ for $n$ large enough does not allow you to conclude that $\lim a_n c_n = - \infty$ because $M$ is a positive number ! If you look at the definition (and your intuition of what it means to tend to $- \infty$), you want to have an upper bound that can go arbitrarily low in the negatives.

I will write an answer here so as to not overflow the comments. I apologize for the long answer, I want to convey as much intuition as possible.
Your proofs are almost correct. Here are a few tips to make sure you do it right.
When you begin your proof by using what you already know about the limits, keep some intuition on the signs. If $\lim a_n = \infty$, you correctly stated that if $M$ is any number, $a_n$ will go higher eventually. BUT you need to think of this $M$ as being REALLY REALLY REALLY BIG (e.g. $10^{(10^{10})}$); in particular, picking a negative $M$ will not allow you to move forward in the proof, you will get stuck, and for a reason: any positive sequence (not necessarily diverging to infinity) are eventually bigger than a negative number. Saying that $a_n \ge -5000$ eventually is true, but does not capture what the limit means. This is the true meaning of diverging to $+\infty$: think of any positive number, my sequence will beat it at some point.
This last paragraph may seem obvious to you. But you need to keep in mind the similar statement for $\lim c_n = -\infty$: the sequence $c_n$ will eventually go lower than any real number, but this is only useful when considering negative numbers. Take any number $M$, which you should think about as MASSIVELY NEGATIVE (e.g. $-1000^{1000^{1000}}$, that's low), $c_n$ will eventually go lower than that. Keep those meanings in mind when writing the proof: do the signs make sense ?
The confusion in your proofs come from the following: if you pick any real number $M$, but then want to consider $\sqrt{M}$ in your proof, you have to require $M$ to be positive (otherwise the square root is not defined), and then $\sqrt{M}$ is also a positive number, it CANNOT go into the negatives. So from now on, think of $M$ as being EXTREMELY HIGH. Now here is how you go about using $\sqrt{M}$ in both cases:

the sequence $(a_n)$ goes to infinity, so at some point it will go higher than $\sqrt{M}$ ($a_n \ge \sqrt{M}$), as you rightfully wrote. Notice that you cannot replace this statement by $a_n \ge -\sqrt{M}$, these two inequalities do not have the same meaning (the first says that $a_n$ is MASSIVE, the second just says that $a_n$ is not too low) ;
the sequence $(c_n)$ goes to negative infinity, so at some point it will go lower than $-\sqrt{M}$ ($c_n \le -\sqrt{M}$), a very negative number. Notice that you cannot replace this statement by $c_n \le \sqrt{M}$, these two inequalities do not have the same meaning (the first says that $c_n$ is MASSIVELY LOW, the second just says that $c_n$ is not too big).

What I hope in writing this whole answer, is that it should become clear why, in your second proof, your statement should rather be "Similarly, $\exists N_2 \in \Bbb N$ such that $c_n \le - \sqrt{M}$ $\forall n \ge N_2$". We need to convey the idea that $c_n$ is REALLY LOW, not that it is smaller than a positive number.

Now this was why you should intuitively write the correct statement to begin with. But this doesn't tell you what goes wrong in your proof if you still start with the (too) weak inequality. I'll write the details of your second proof to show you what fails.
Here is what you wrote: fix any $M > 0$ (positive so as to make sure $\sqrt{M}$ exists). Since $\lim a_n = \infty$, there exists $N_1 \in \Bbb N$ such that $a_n \ge \sqrt{M}$ for all $n \ge N_1$ (correct inequality). Similarly, there exists $N_2 \in \Bbb N$ such that $-c_n \ge -\sqrt{M}$ for all $n \ge N_2$ (technically true, but insufficient to conclude, as we will see).
You then claim that if $n \ge N = \max(N_1,N_2)$,  we have $-a_n c_n \ge -M$. This is technically correct again, but notice what goes wrong: if $n$ is VERY BIG, then $a_n$ and $-c_n$ are VERY BIG POSITIVE NUMBERS, whereas $-M$ is a VERY LOW NEGATIVE NUMBER. In order to state that $\lim -a_n c_n = +\infty$, you need to argue that $-a_n c_n$ goes higher that any arbitrary POSITIVE number, which is not the case here (you got stuck with negative numbers because of the insufficient inequality with $c_n$ you started with).

Is it fine to fix any $\varepsilon \gt 0$ $\exists N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n \ge \varepsilon$ $\forall n \ge N_1$, and then suppose a $M \lt 0$, $\exists N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $c_n \le \frac{M}{\varepsilon}$ $\forall n \ge N_2$ which clearly show that $\varepsilon$ can be positive arbitrary large, and $\frac{M}{\varepsilon}$ is negative arbitrary large. Therefore we don't have to stuck with the negativity of inequalities. Clearly, $-c_n \ge -\frac{M}{\varepsilon}$ the two sides are both positive and $-a_nc_n \ge -M$ which is $a_nc_n \le M$ in which the product tends to -\infty

That is one way to do it, but it is a little clumsy because the letter $\epsilon$ is usually reserved for arguments it which we want $\epsilon$ to be arbitrary small ; whereas in this case, you only use it as bounding $(a_n)$ from below. Other than that, this is correct.

Notice that your argument shows something stronger: if $(a_n)$ is any sequence which is eventually greater than some fixed positive $k>0$ (not necessarily tending to infinity) and if $\lim c_n = -\infty$, then $\lim a_n c_n = - \infty$. I'll let you observe which other statement you can prove this way with signs reverses.
